# Exponentially weighted averages graph (Exponential smoothing)

Tags: statistics, optimization, machine-learning

The equation for Exponential Smoothing is defined as:
[Exponential Smoothing equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXo26.png)

When we increase `a`, the red line will be shifted to the right. How come does that happen while the red line is being restricted by given dataset? Thanks in advance.

[Graph of exponentially weighted averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg1ns.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please consider learning mathjax typesetting as it is used on the site and try to avoid links to formula.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data given by $\{x_n\}$, the exponential smoothing output is written:
$$ s_t = \alpha x_t + (1-\alpha)s_{t-1} $$
where $s_0 = x_0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Notice that when $\alpha\rightarrow 0$, we get $s_t \rightarrow s_{t-1} = x_0$, meaning the output will be a constant *that pays no attention to the data*. When $\alpha\rightarrow 1$, we get $s_t\rightarrow x_t $, i.e. no smoothing is being done (we are just copying the data).

As for the shifting, notice that every output point is a weighted average of the current point $x_t$ and an average encapsulating the *previous* points $s_{t-1}$. This means that the more we weight $s_{t-1}$, the more we are weighting the *previous* time points. Thus, decreasing $\alpha$ (which increases the weight on $s_{t-1}$) will "shift the curve left", because it is forcing the output at time $t$ to better match the values at the *previous* time points.
Increasing $\alpha$ will have the opposite effect.

Comment: Thank you it helps so much

Comment: @BillPham If it answers your question, you can click the checkmark to mark the answer as accepted :)